# Launch TestNG debug with JVM args from build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, testng, aspectj

I have a Gradle project where the tests run using TestNG. (I use Intellij IDEA)

I need an aspectjweaver to be launched each time on tests execution. The aspectjweaver is defined as JVM argument and added to applicationDefaultJvmArgs in Build.gradle:

```
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'application'
def aspectjVersion = "1.8.7"
mainClassName = 'exa.tags.runner.TestManager'
applicationDefaultJvmArgs=["-javaagent:APP_HOME_PLACEHOLDER/lib/aspectjweaver-${aspectjVersion}.jar"]

dependencies {
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:${aspectjVersion}"
}

def weaver = configurations.compile.find { it.name.contains("aspectjweaver") }

startScripts << {
    unixScript.text = unixScript.text.replace('APP_HOME_PLACEHOLDER', '\$APP_HOME')
    windowsScript.text = windowsScript.text.replace('APP_HOME_PLACEHOLDER', '%APP_HOME%')
}

run {
    doFirst {
        jvmArgs = jvmArgs.grep {
            !it.contains('APP_HOME_PLACEHOLDER')
        }
        jvmArgs = jvmArgs << "-javaagent:$weaver"
    }
}
```

So when I launch tests using this run task, everything works fine for me. 
But the problem is that when I right click on a test and select TestNG Run or Debug, the aspectj is not launched.

When I used maven, the aspectjweaver was added as an argLine to the maven-surefire-plugin and worked each time (debug, run single test or execute mvn test goal).

So, what is the proper way and place to set the JVM argument to the actual version of AspectJ? I tried to add the path to aspecj.jar as default arg in Edit configurations. That worked, but in such a case I depend on a specific cached file.

Can this be done somewhere in project files without changing the IDE configurations?

**UPDATE**

I tried to add a test task in my build.gradle:

```
def weaver = configurations.compile.find { it.name.contains("aspectjweaver") }

test {
    useTestNG()
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    println "Adding aspectJ weaver: ${weaver}"
    jvmArgs = jvmArgs << "-javaagent:$weaver"
}
```

And now I see this output on each task execution (e.g. when I run clean task).

But when I right click on test and select Debug

[image]

I do not see the output. 
Looks like the task 'test' is not executed when I select run one test with TestNG.

Comment: Have you tried `jvmArgs` for the `test` configuration? See Gradle documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

Comment: Yes, I did. I updated the description. I am new to Gradle and definitely do something wrongly.

Comment: So as far as I understood, this is not possible, as on TestNG run/debug a separate JVM gets created, so gradle tasks will not influence it. I added a JMV option with the path to aspectj weaver to TestNG defaults directly in IDEA Edit configurations.